# Mean field theory of Potts model (equation solution)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mean-field-theory

When considering a $q$ states Potts model in mean field approximation, one finds the following free energy:
$$ \beta f(s) = \frac{1+(q-1)s}{q}\log{\left[ 1 + (q-1)s \right]} + \frac{(q-1)(1-s)}{q}\log{\left(1-s\right)} - \frac{q-1}{2q} z K s^2 $$
where $s \in [0,1[$ is a properly defined order parameter, $z$ the lattice coordination number and $K=\beta J$.
The critical point is found solving $f(s)=0$ and $f'(s)=0$ simoultaneously, so far so good.

The exact solution to these equations are

$$ s_c = \frac{q-2}{q-1} $$
$$ zK_c = 2\frac{q-1}{q-2} \log{(q-1)} $$
(and of course $s=0$). You can easily check by substitution that these are indeed the solutions.

My question: is there a way to find out these solutions starting from the equations? Or are these solutions just an unbelievably smart guess?

PS: the derivative is given by

$$ \beta f'(s) = \frac{q-1}{q} \left[ \log{\frac{1+(q-1)s}{1-s}} - zKs \right] $$

Comment: Your question assumes that one start from the expression for $\beta f(s)$, then calculate $f'(s)$ and solves the system of equations $\beta f(s)=0$ and $\beta f'(s)=0$? If you mean this, there is a way how to solve the system but do it by hand may so time-consuming. Therefore, you can try use any soft to solve the system

Comment: Well, since I know the solutions, I understand my question is not that relevant. However I am just wondering if there is a way to solve it by hand

Comment: Substituting in the solutions suggests that $q = 1 \pm i$ and that only the real part of the free energy is $0$ at the critical point (imaginary part being $\pi/2$).  I don't claim to understand.

Comment: $q$ is a known parameter in the Potts model, and you can assume it is an integer greater than 2